# Plot of $f'(x)$ against $f(x)$

Tags: derivatives, calculus

What does the plot of $f'(x)$ against $f(x)$ represent?

Comment: In one-dimensional motion, take *x* to represent time, and *f* position, so you are discussing a plot of velocity versus position.

Comment: I understand that, but what exactly does the velocity against position plot describe?

Comment: Describe? A portal to undefined profundity? How did you define "describe"?

Comment: This is not a physics question.

Comment: FWIW, it can be quite illuminating to plot speed vs displacement. Try it with a body in an elliptical orbit. Feynman has a nice discussion about this (maybe in *Six Easy Pieces*).

Comment: A plot of velocity against position tells you what the velocity was when the position was in different places or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

In conservative and non-conservative *dynamical system analysis* such as ( Limit cycles, Van der Pol equation of oscillation, Lissajou's figures involving vibration in two directions/frequencies etc.) DEs of two, three variables are together considered coupled or decoupled. They  occur in mechanical or electrical dynamic systems.

They can be represented as *phase portraits* which are displacement/velocity plots. We  see how much deviation is there from simplest harmonic model situation (ellipse) due to oscillations in-phase, out of phase or partial offset at start points of prescribed boundary values.The plot can visually display effects of stiffness or damping.

In [Lyapunev Stability](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5PgJgdlz_Y) $( \dot x, \ddot x) $ of *state variables*  we see elliptic points, saddle points etc., characterizing the dynamics coming out of the governing ODE or transfer function.

[image]

Phase portraits are a characteristic of the entire dynamical process.

[Van der Pol Oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pol_oscillator)

Answer (score 0):

It represents the derivative in terms of the original function. Without context, that's as much as I can answer.

Comment: Lets suppose $f(x)$ is displacement and $x$ is time.

Comment: Well assuming that  the displacement vs time function is either monotonically increasing of decreasing, then $f$ vs $f'$ would represent the linear position vs velocity graph. I say monotonically because if your function $f(x)$ increases then decreases, then for the same displacement, it will have 2 different possible values of velocity. So you'd have to figure out which speed you need.

Comment: I see! That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the only thing you can tell from a velocity-displacement graph is what the velocity is given the displacement, and vice-versa (although if the graph isn't one-to-one, then we may have various different values of displacement for a given value of velocity).